# C++ protobuf uses much more memory than what is required to hold the message

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am having trouble using protocol buffers to store large objects (in this example, they occupy about 200 MB when serialized to binary files). It seems to me that the C++ implementation requires much more than 200MB of space to hold them, and I am not sure if this is expected or if I am doing something wrong.

I am using protocol buffer version 3.5.1. Here is a working example.

I would expect that to hold 5 copies of the protobuf message in memory ~1GB of memory should be sufficient, although from the example below it seems that the code requires between 5 and 10GB. Is this a drawback of protobuf, a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Here is my cpp file.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "../generated_src/leviosa.pb.h"

template <class ProtoMessage>
ProtoMessage deserializeProtobufFromFile(std::string filename) {
  ProtoMessage m;
  std::string s_json;
  std::fstream input(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  if (!input) {
    throw std::runtime_error(filename + ": file not found.");
  } else if (!m.ParseFromIstream(&input)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to parse " + filename +
                             " as binary protobuf.");
  }

  return m;
}

using namespace std;
using namespace leviosa;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  OfflineOutput proto0 =
      deserializeProtobufFromFile<OfflineOutput>("offline0.lev");

  cout << "Read from file completed." << endl;

  auto p1(proto0);
  cout << "First copy completed." << endl;

  auto p2(p1);
  cout << "Another copy completed." << endl;

  auto p3(p1);
  cout << "Another copy completed." << endl;

  auto p4(p1);
  cout << "Another copy completed." << endl;

  cout << "Done." << endl;
}
```

Here is (part of) the proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package leviosa;


message OleSender{
    int64 a = 1;
    int64 b = 2;
}

message OleReceiver{
    int64 x = 1;
    int64 z = 2; 
}

message Ole{
    oneof ole_oneof {
        OleSender sender = 1;
        OleReceiver receiver = 2;
    }
}

message OleVector{
    repeated Ole ole = 1;
}

message WatchInfoPerServer{
    bytes prg = 1;
    OleVector oles = 2;
    int64 degree_test_blind_share = 4; 
    int64 perm_test_blind_share = 5; 
}

message OfflineOutput{
    repeated bytes prg_seeds = 1;
    repeated OleVector oles_for_servers = 2;

    bytes degree_test_blind_poly = 3;
    bytes perm_test_blind_shares = 4;

    oneof commit {
        bytes commitment = 5;
        bytes randomness_committed = 6;
    }

    map<int32,WatchInfoPerServer> watchlist = 7;

}
```

This is an example run of my program. It runs without issues with 10GB of memory, but aborts with 5GB:

```
$ls -al offline0.lev 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 antonio antonio 186560583 Aug 27 17:57 offline0.lev
$ ulimit -v 10000000
$ ./test  
Read from file completed.
First copy completed.
Another copy completed.
Another copy completed.
Another copy completed.
Done.
$ ulimit -v 5000000
$ ./test 
Read from file completed.
First copy completed.
Another copy completed.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf compresses the data when you serialize it, so it is expected that is uses more memory if you deserialize it to your ram.